# Convert path to one get variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How would I go about transforming this URL:

`http://example.com/this/is/my/path.html
http://example.com/this/is/my/path.html?var=2&varr=3`

to this:

`http://example.com?path=this/is/my/path.html
http://example.com?path=this/is/my/path.html&var=2&varr=3`

I've seen many tutorials on how to convert it to multiple get variables but none for the whole path that included the get variables as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my edit below

Try this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?path=$1 [QSA]
```

The first part of the RewriteRule will capture the full path without the query string (GET parameters). The second part of the RewriteRule will rewrite with a GET parameter named "path" containing the full path we captured before. And then, using the [QSA] flag (which should be default behaviour of Apache), we tell Apache to keep the original GET parameters and append then to the new query string.

**EDIT :**

There is a major problem with this answer, a redirection loop. Here a better solution :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !path=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer okio.  I am actually in the midst of doing server maintenance but I will test this out when it's all over (a few hours).  Will accept at that time!  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Okio, I'm now having this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23483444/htaccess-request-exceeded-the-limit-of-10-internal-redirects-due-to-probable-con. Do you have any insight as to what is going on?