# htaccess Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error

Tags: .htaccess

I get this error in my logs.  The htaccess is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?path=$1 [QSA]
```

and is an answer to the question: 
[Convert path to one get variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23329488/convert-path-to-one-get-variable)

I tested it via http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ and it says that the code SHOULD work.  I'm assuming that this code keeps redirecting but how it does I have no idea.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm totally in the deep end.

Edit:
Full error log is as follows:
`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, my previous answer was wrong. Of course there is an redirection loop with this. We have to add a RewriteCond to check if there is already a "path" parameter, which means there already have been a redirection.

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !path=
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: It works!!  When I checked it last time, I had done it against the htaccess.madewithlove.be site because I had put the servers down for some time and wanted to accept your answer.  Thanks Okio!